# Configure Linux and PHP to send email via script instead of SMTP

Tags: ubuntu, php, email, sendmail, php.ini

I have a server with a static IP and also a domain pointing to it. Because it is behind a firewall that blocks SMTP (ingoing and outgoing), I am not able to send any EMail from it.

To be able to send and receive EMail with the domain anyways, I use [Mailgun](http://mailgun.com).

I can send EMail with GMail, for example - but not with PHP, since I have only found instructions to configure sendmail() using SMTP. Fortunately, Mailgun offers a HTTPS API to send EMail.

**The question**

How can I configure PHP to call a script on my server, which itself calls the Mailgun API?

Note: calling the API is not the issue. I only need help configuring PHP.

**What I have tried**

In the php.ini, you can set the path to the sendmail binary like this:

```
sendmail_path = /path/to/sendmail
```

I pointed this to a script which just dumps all params into a file:

```
echo "$@" > /path/to/output.txt
```

The script indeed gets called whenever `mail()` in PHP is called, but apparently there is a problem with the parameters. When I `cat output.txt`, I only get two empty lines.

Comment: I have never used Mailgun. yet I feel its worth looking at PHPXmail/phpmailer as a different solution..  http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/send-email-from-a-page/using-phpmailer-to-send-mail-through-php

Comment: Mailgun is actually a service provider that hosts the SMTP server for you. Using phpmailer is not a solution because it, too, relies on the SMTP port being open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. It was simply that `mail()` feeds the headers and contents of the mail into the `stdin` of the respective `sendmail` binary/script.

So I adapted my script to read from `stdin` and that indeed worked.

Credit to [this tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-log-emails-sent-with-phps-mail-function-to-detect-form-spam), which brought me on the right track.